# Java - how to clear message after display in view

Tags: java

I want display error message in my view `home.jsp` using `<c:out value="${message}" />`. But after displaying it, I want to clear it. any idea?

Comment: Can't you clear it on the next line?? by using `<c:set>` ?? Or you can explain better.. where are you getting this message from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes` to your `@RequestMapping` function arguments and set the attribute using:

```
redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "whatever went wrong") ;
return "redirect:/path_to_your_view" ;
```

remember: This works hand-in-hand with Spring's `redirect:` functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ajax` OR Plain `Javascript`.

Another way will be to refresh the complete page; but not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to clear it automatically you could use something such as JQuery's [`.delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) to do an action after a given period of time, which could be either redirecting the user to another page or else simply hiding the `div` used to render the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript method `setTimeout()`
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp